# How can I specify the position of a given symbol in a substring function?

Tags: mysql, sql, position, substring

Let's suppose I have this column with this kind of data:

```
IT > FR
ES > PT 
FR > IT
```

And I want to show two separate columns, where the results are: in the first, only the country code of the first country and, in the second, only the ones of the second.

We use the substring function. And it's okay.

Now, let's assume I have this column called border:

```
IT > FR
ES > PT 
FR > IT
DE > PORTO
ES > NL
NO2 > UK
```

The length of the borders are not the same!

Is there a way to specify in the substring function that I want for a column only the string from the position of `>` backwards or onwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php

```
Locate([your column],'>',1)
```

Or am I missing something?

```
Left([Your column],Locate([your column],'>',1)-1) --To grab the left side
Right([Your column],Locate([your column],'>',1)+1) --to grab the right side
```

Comment: normally I would write SELECT substring(border, 1, 2) as BLABLA  
FROM DB1; and it would retrieve me for example only IT or ES, 
but i do have also few expections that are not only two characters but 6. so i want to have a command that takes everything left (or right) of the > symbol.

@ChrisG

Comment: @Enrico check out the new updates, let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(border, ' > ', 1) as country_1,
       substring_index(border, ' > ', -1) as country_2
```

This is a built-in MySQL function.  Note that this is using spaces around the `'>'`, because that seems to be how your data is structured.